# Spark Dataframe writing issue in azure from spark: One of the request inputs is not valid

Tags: azure, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I am able to read data from azure blob storage but when  writing back to azure storage then it throws below error . I am running this program in my local machine.
Can someone help me out on this please.

**My Program**

val conf = new SparkConf()
val config = new SparkConf();

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("AzureConnector ").config(config).master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

try {
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")

  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.wasbs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.azure.account.key.**myaccount**.blob.core.windows.net",
    "**mykey**")

 
  val csvDf = spark.read.csv("wasbs://workspaces@myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/test/test.csv")
  csvDf.show()
  csvDf.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").mode("append").save("wasbs://workspaces@myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/test/output")

} catch {
  case e: Exception => {
    e.printStackTrace()
  }
}
```

**Error**

> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException:
> com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: One of the request
> inputs is not valid.  at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.rename(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2482)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$FolderRenamePending.execute(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:424)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.rename(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1997)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:435)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:415)
> at
> org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.performCommit$1(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:50)
> at
> org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.commitTask(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:76)
> at
> org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitTask(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:153)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:260)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
> at
> org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:191)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)  at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: One of the request
> inputs is not valid.  at
> com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:162)
> at
> com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:307)
> at
> com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:177)
> at
> com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.startCopyFromBlob(CloudBlob.java:764)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.StorageInterfaceImpl$CloudBlobWrapperImpl.startCopyFromBlob(StorageInterfaceImpl.java:399)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.rename(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2449)
> ... 19 more

Comment: Generally speaking, you cannot append a Blob. Have you tried mode("overwrite")?

Comment: joel, I tired but this is not the issue. I suspect some setting is missing in spark.conf for azure but not sure what that setting is

Answer (score 1):

Using the WASB driver as a client to a hierarchical namespace enabled storage account isn't supported. Instead, we recommend that you use the Azure Blob File System (ABFS) driver in your Hadoop environment [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-known-issues#windows-azure-storage-blob-wasb-driver-unsupported-with-data-lake-storage-gen2)

Check if your storage account is an adls gen2 (hierarchical namespace is enabled)